# Can I use a GLM in R to analyse the relationship between time-series environmental variables?

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-linear-model, environmental-data

I have a water quality sensor which is measuring various parameters every hour for one year in the same location. I would like to analyse the relationship between each of these parameters and determine whether it is significant over the time series, would a GLM be appropriate for this or not given the potential interdependence of the variables? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A GLM is a model of the relationship between a dependent variable $Y$ and independent explanatory variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_p$. Have you thought about how/if this is related to your goal of analyzing the relationships between (pairs of) variables?